# How to print all lines from log file after a specific word up to end of paragraph?

Tags: windows, batch-file, text

I have a log file like below:

```
Beginning difffull backup for database Managed_Metadata_Service, 3 of 149.
Full: 0   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Full: 4   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Backup of Managed_Metadata_Service failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.

Beginning difffull backup for database model, 4 of 149.
Full: 0   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Full: 2   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Full: 4   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Backup of model failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.

Beginning difffull backup for database msdb, 5 of 149.
Full: 0   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Full: 4   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Backup of msdb failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.

Beginning difffull backup for database Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB, 6 of 149.
Full: 0   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Full: 4   Read: 6144  Written: 0  Rate: 0.00 Kb/Sec
Backup of Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
```

How can I find all occurrences of `failed` and then print the line with this word and the next lines until end of message which means until next dot at end of paragraph or end of file?

The result would be like this:

```
Backup of Managed_Metadata_Service failed. 
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
.
.
Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB failed. 
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
```

For all lines with `failed` word.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set numbers=
for /F "delims=^" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"failed" Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log') do (
    set /A sameline=%%a, after=%%a+1
    set "numbers=!numbers!!sameline!: !after!: "
)
rem Search for the lines
(
    for /F "tokens=* delims=^ %%a in ('findstr /N "^" Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do echo %%b
) > result.txt
```

Comment: `find "failed" file.log` ?

Comment: i have to create a batch file to find it and print line that contain the word (failed) and next lines with message of error

Comment: @CienzoJoshua, highlight/select your file content and then press the **`{}`** button.

Comment: done thanks Compo bye

Comment: @Mofi are you sure about the line breaks between `failed.` and `ANS0238E `? Seems to be one line to me.

Comment: If there *is* a line break: `findstr "failed\.$ ^ANS" file.log`

Comment: Also, you say "I have to create a batch file to find it and print line that contain the word (failed) and next lines with message of error." I don't believe that is your actual requirement. I think want you really want is just to find and print the line containing the word 'failed' and the following lines. Writing a batch file for it is not a requirement, but what is in your opinion the best way to implement it. Let those answering decide what is the best way to implement it. I think the single-line answer from Stephan is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution as suggested by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) for this log file example is:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "failed\.$ ^ANS" "Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log"
```

This single command line outputs:

```
Backup of Managed_Metadata_Service failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
Backup of model failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
Backup of msdb failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
Backup of Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB failed.
ANS0238E (RC2041) The sequence of calls is invalid.
```

**FINDSTR** searches for either a line ending with `failed.` **or** a line starting with `ANS` and outputs those lines. The dot must be in the regular expression search string with a backslash to be interpreted as literal character. A multi-line regular expression search is not supported by **FINDSTR**.

Alternate **FINDSTR** command line also running two regular expression searches on each line **OR** combined:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:failed\.$ /C:^ANS "Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log"
```

---

A more complex solution is using this batch code:

```
@echo off
if not exist "Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log" goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PrintLines="

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^" "Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log"') do (
    if "%%J" == "" (
        set "PrintLines="
    ) else (
        set "Line=%%J"
        if not "!Line:failed=!" == "!Line!" set "PrintLines=1"
    )
    if defined PrintLines echo %%J
)

endlocal
```

The output is the same. This code outputs any line containing anywhere case-insensitive `failed` and outputs this line as well as all other lines up to next empty line in file. An empty line does not contain any character, not even a space or horizontal tab character.

There are two issues with this code:

1. Lines starting with one or more colons are not correct output as all colons at start of a line are removed by `delims=:` required to split up each line output by **FINDSTR** with line number, colon and line itself.
   **FINDSTR** is used to process by **FOR** even empty lines because all lines including empty lines start with line number and colon after running **FINDSTR** on file searching for begin of a line which results in a positive match on every line.
2. Lines containing one or more exclamation marks are not correct output because of enabled delayed environment variable expansion applied on command line `set "Line=%%J"` after replacing `%%J` by the line from file.

---

Another not 100% perfect solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PrintLines="

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("Backup_DIFF_2017-12-14.log") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    if "!Line:~0,9!" == "Beginning" (
        set "PrintLines="
    ) else (
        if not "!Line:failed=!" == "!Line!" set "PrintLines=1"
    )
    if defined PrintLines echo %%I
)

endlocal
```

In comparison to second solution this batch code interprets case-sensitive `Beginning` at begin of a line as new paragraph instead of an empty line. For that reason the command **FOR** can process the file directly with ignoring empty lines.

But also this solution has two issues:

1. Lines starting with a semicolon are ignored by **FOR** as `;` is the default for option `eol` not explicitly set to a different character. This issue can be solved by specifying `eol=` with a character which definitely never exists at beginning of a line in the log file.
2. Lines containing one or more exclamation marks are not correct output because of enabled delayed environment variable expansion applied on command line `set "Line=%%I"` after replacing `%%I` by the line from file.

It is expected by this solution that a line starting with `Beginning` does not contain the word `failed` anywhere in the line.

---

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`